# I want to unlock my Samsung a70 without factory reset

Tags: samsung

My son played with my phone and changed my password and I don't know what is it. I have tried for several months but nothing worked.

Can you please help me because my phone contains important images and files that I want to save.

Comment: give it back to your son and let him play with, hopefully one day he remember

Comment: no he is small and he can't remember because he did random

Comment: obviously he was smart enough to watch you unlocking, remembering the unlock code, navigating to settings - security - screen lock - successfully inputting unlock code - typing new "random" password - repeating new "random" password exactly again - and confirming the change